# Wordpress class, using add_action to call member function does not work

Tags: plugin-development, functions, filters, actions, oop

I'm learning to create a WP plugin as a class. However, it seems the add_action doesn't work when calling my function; it works when using $this->init().

Example:

```
    class test
{

    public $age = NULL;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //register an activation hook
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( &$this, 'installplugin' ) );

        add_action('init', array( &$this, 'init' ) ); //this doesn't work
        //$this->init(); //This WORKS!

    }

    function installplugin()
    {

        add_option( 'age', 45 );
        $this->init();  

    }

    function init()
    {

        $age = get_option( 'age' );
        $this->age = $age;



    }

    function printAge(  )
    {
        echo "The age is " . $this->age . "<br />";
    }

}
```

So, after running:

```
$learnObj =  new learnable_test();

$learnObj->printAge();
```

It only prints: "The age is "

But if I were t comment out the add_action('init',...) and use the $this->init(), that seems to work, printing "The age is 45"

What am I missing?

Comment: You are sure that when you call `$learnObj->printAge();` 'init' action was already _done_, aren't you?

Comment: If it was already done, then shouldn't $this->age be initialize with the value 45? Then when I called printAge(), the value of $this->age should already be set, right?

Comment: where do you create your class instance: `$learnObj =  new learnable_test();`?

Comment: 'init' action does not mean "class inizialization", it is an action performed by wordpress after the theme is included and after all the stuff under `after_setup_theme` hook are done. If this is a plugin (and so it seems) you can replace `add_action('init'` with  `add_action('plugins_loaded'` that is performed before. Better you can: `$learnObj = new learnable_test( get_option('age') );` and in the class `public function __construct($age) { $this->age = $age;`. Doing so init method is not needed...

Comment: Also don't use `&$this` unless you're stuck in a time machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it can't and won't work like you want it to.

Let's look at what exactly are you doing.

Inside your constructor you have:

```
add_action('init', array( &$this, 'init' ) ); //this doesn't work
```

So you add `init` method of your object to WPs `init` hook. When WP runs it's `init` action, then your `init` method will be run to, but not sooner and not later.

Then you do something like this:

```
$learnObj =  new learnable_test();

$learnObj->printAge();
```

So you create object of your class. It will add `$learnObj->init` to WPs `init` hook.

If you call these 2 lines after WPs `init` hook was already done, nothing will happen.

If you call them before (I guess you do) - your `$learnObj->init` will be executed during WPs `init` action (and `age` variable will be set).

But in the second line you want to access this `age` variable. It won't be set here yet, because WP haven't yet executed it's `init` action, thus your `$learnObj->init` hasn't been executed too.

Comment: In short: call `$learnObj = new learnable_test();` **before** 'init' is done and `$learnObj->printAge();` **after** 'init' is done. :)